# Bind the Result of one dataset to an another

Tags: json, dashboard, einstein-analytics, saql

I have two steps.

One with my Holidays group by years and month created with a single dataset with one column "Holidays" with all date of holidays in 2018 and 2019.

The second one is my Amount per day where I already filtered week-end with this SAQL code :

```
q = load "Test";
a = load "Date_Test";
b = load "Test";
a = foreach a generate day_in_week(toDate('Date', "dd/MM/yyyy")) as 'DayOfWeek', 'Date_Year' as 'Date_Year', 'Date_Month' as 'Date_Month';
a = filter a by DayOfWeek not in [1,7];
a = group a by ('Date_Year', 'Date_Month');
b = group b by ('CloseDate_Year', 'CloseDate_Month');
q = group a by 'Date_Month', b by 'CloseDate_Month';
q = foreach q generate a.'Date_Year' as 'CloseDate_Year', a.'Date_Month' as 'CloseDate_Month', sum(b.'Amount')/count(a) as 'sum_Amount';
q = order q by ('CloseDate_Year' asc, 'CloseDate_Month' asc);
q = limit q 2000;
```

Now in my dashboard I want to bind my step called `ApWD_1` with the result of my step `Holidays_1` I tried this but the query is not valid :

```
"query":"filter:"[["Holidays", "{{column(Holidays_1, \"Holidays\").asObject}}"]],
"q = load \"Test\";\na = load \"Dates_Holidays\";\nb = load \"Test\";\na = foreach a generate day_in_week(toDate('Date', \"dd/MM/yyyy\")) as 'DayOfWeek', 'Date_Year' as 'Date_Year', 'Date_Month' as 'Date_Month';\na = filter a by DayOfWeek not in [1,7];\na = group a by ('Date_Year', 'Date_Month');\nb = group b by ('CloseDate_Year', 'CloseDate_Month');\nq = group a by 'Date_Month', b by 'CloseDate_Month';\nq = foreach q generate a.'Date_Year' as 'CloseDate_Year', a.'Date_Month' as 'CloseDate_Month', sum(b.'Amount')/count(a) as 'sum_Amount';\nq = order q by ('CloseDate_Year' asc, 'CloseDate_Month' asc);\nq = limit q 2000;",
```

In conclusion I want to filter my ApWD result by Holidays result and supress all date in Holidays date.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you are trying to achieve here and also which step is trying to control,

Anyhow, if you want to bind them at filter level try using "asEquality" instead of as Object as shown below

```
q = filter q by {{cell(stepFoo.selection, 1, <column from stepFoo>).asEquality(<column from q DS>)}};
```

This will internally generate in or range filters which you need.